# How do I execute the command 'appcfg rollback'?

Tags: linux, google-app-engine, netbeans, fedora

While uploading the project , there was a network failure and I had to stop, when the uploading process was only 31% complete. Now when I click to deploy application to google app engine the following message is produced :

```
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: 
https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=programworks&version=1&
409 Conflict
Another transaction by user suhailgupta03 is already in progress for app: 
s~programworks, version: 1. That user can undo the transaction with 
"appcfg rollback".

Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=programworks&version=1&
409 Conflict
Another transaction by user suhailgupta03 is already in progress for app: 
s~programworks, version: 1. That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg rollback".
```

I open my shell prompt and type in there `appcfg rollback` but I get a message that this command is not found.I have installed google app engine as a plugin for netbeans.

The path where I have kept the jars of google app engine : `/home/non-admin/appengine-java-sdk-1.6.6/lib/`

Please tell what should I do to rollback the previous process ? I badly need to upload the *war* file.!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You want `appcfg.sh rollback` (which is in `path_to_your_app_engine_sdk/bin/`). `appcfg` comes in different variants for each type of runtime (Python, Java, Go), so the suggested command is a bit generic.

If, for whatever reason, you don't have easy access to the entire war directory of your project (if, for example your IDE only gives you a .war file), you can do the following:

1. Make a directory named `war`.
2. Inside the *war* folder make another directory and name it as `WEB-INF`.
3. In the folder `WEB-INF` drop two xml files, namely `web.xml` and `appengine-web.xml`. These should have the contents of your deployed `web.xml` and `appengine-web.xml` files respectively.

Then run the following shell command (this assumes you execute it from the `bin` directory of the App Engine Java SDK):

```
[non-admin@user bin]$ ./appcfg.sh rollback /home/non-admin/NetBeansProjects/PersonalSite/web/war
```

If you are using the Go appengine tools, then you'll need to run:

```
$ cd [your go_appengine directory]
$ ./appcfg.py rollback [your app directory with app.yaml in it]
```

Comment: `appcfg.sh rollback` after being inside the directory _bin_

Comment: Which `bin` is it? Is `bin` in your $PATH? If it's the sdk/bin/ you might try using `./appcfg.sh rollback` instead.

Comment: [I am inside the bin directory of the server's sdk.](http://i45.tinypic.com/2ahi8lw.png)

Comment: I tried the `./appcfg.sh rollback` command after being inside the bin directory the server's sdk and [this](http://i47.tinypic.com/2gufk42.png) is what message I got. What is the reason for this ?

Comment: Can you do an `ls` of the directory you are in? Is there a file named appcfg.sh in there?

Comment: Is there anything I am missing ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14482/discussion-between-dan-holevoet-and-suhail-gupta)

Comment: Hi.@DanHolevoet, I don't really konw if u can see this message, but BTW. Why if i've typed `sudo  appcfg.cmd rollback "/Documents/workspace/server side/war"` from the **appcfg**'s dir i'm still getting this error `sudo: appcfg.cmd: command not found`, and all files inside war dir are ok. appreciate it.

Comment: If you are using maven, the bin dir would be similar to  /.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.4/appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.4/bin

Comment: When the .sh file has no executable priviledges, the message file not found is displayed. select all files in the bin directory, right click and select "properties" in the privildges tab check the executable checkbox

Answer (score 18):

If you are using windows, follow the same steps given above and run command in DOS prompt..

C:\eclipse-jee-helios-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbund
le_1.7.3\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.3\bin> **appcfg.cmd** ***rollback*** "C:\home\myweb\war"

Comment: Thank you.  This answer is what I need.  In addition to your step, you may have to upgrade your appengine sdk.  You may get "Bad authentication response: 404 Not Found" if you have older appengine sdk.  Older sdk uses https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin, which is deprecated.  We need to move to newer sdk to use oauth2.  Newer sdk will redirect you to browser to login and gives you a code.  Copy and paste the code back to the command prompt.

Answer (score 13):

Another easy way is given below:

1. to change the version number in app.yaml...
2. then deploy new version,
3. and finally delete the old version via google app engine webform

Edit:

to answer dg99's question: 
the version code you need to change is up to you (it is the version of your application)

Comment: Answering an ancient, resolved question is probably only going to be helpful if you include the same level of detail as the accepted answer.  What code is required to change the version number in `app.yaml`?  What is an example of the before and after of that change?  How does one deploy a new version?  etc.

Comment: I just wanted to help others which are  running into the same issue as I did (i dont care how old this thread is - I had this problem these days so maybe others are interested to). Yes it was already resolved but I give a different solution which is more easy and faster so I just thought it helps.

Comment: This helped me in Android Studio. I updated the version number in appengine-web.xml

Answer (score 2):

This works for me!! (Win OS)

C:\eclipse-jee-helios-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbund le_1.7.3\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.3\bin> appcfg.cmd rollback C:\home\myweb\war

Answer (score 2):

If you are using eclipse & maven build envrioment,
maybe you are uploading application by maven command, **appengine:update**, right ?

Then, when you have a problem like that "409 Conflict".
You can use maven command on eclipse->project->run as->maven build...->
**"appengine:rollback"**

Try this. I solved problem by this way

Answer (score 1):

After trying to rollback for a while without any success (I was prompted for user/pass endlessly ) I thought It might be because of my two phase/factor authentication,

So the following way solved it all:

1. open command prompt (*cmd.exe*) in `D:\Java\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.3\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.3\bin>` (or look for the location of your `appcfg.cmd` somewhere else)
2. type in: `appcfg.cmd --oauth2 rollback D:/Java/workspace/my_app/war`
3. Then I was prompted with oauth2 token in my browser , did copy and got back to the cmd than paste
4. That's it! Deploy to App Engine works again!

Comment: It says: Either the access code is invalid or the OAuth token is revoked.Details: invalid_grant

Answer (score 1):

Use this for backends developed in Android Studio:

```
cd project_path/project_name/module_name/src/main
appcfg.sh rollback webapp
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the following worked fine out of the development directory where my app.yaml was located.

`appcfg.py rollback .`

I'm using the Python SDK though, might be different for Java since the `<app-directory>` is called `<war-location>` there.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to be followed for rollback in windows 7 using command prompt:

1) first set the environment variale for python.(so that command "python" is accepted by the      command prompt).

2) then type: "python" give_space "path to appcfg.py file" give_space "rollback" give_space "path to your project".(**PLease note you should specify your paths within inverted commas**).

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Maven then `appengine:rollback` command works.
This works even when it is an Eclipse Maven project.

To roll back in Eclipse Maven follow this process -

Run -> Build -> Goals (appengine:rollback) -> Apply -> Run

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm as some of the answers clarified above.

If you use `mvn appengine:update` to deploy, you can use `mvn appengine:rollback` to do the rollback.