# How do I rollback app-engine deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, rollback

I have an Appengine connected android project (eclipse). I am trying to deploy it as I have done countless times. But this time I am getting the following error.

> Unable to update app: Error posting to URL:
>   https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=myappid&version=1&
>   409 Conflict Another transaction by user myusername is already in
>   progress for app: s~myappid, version: 1. That user can undo the
>   transaction with "appcfg rollback".
>
> See the deployment console for more details Unable to update app:
>   Error posting to URL:
>   https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=myappid&version=1&
>   409 Conflict Another transaction by user myusername is already in
>   progress for app: s~myappid, version: 1. That user can undo the
>   transaction with "appcfg rollback".

So I open my osx terminal and navigate to the folder of my project. When I type

```
appcfg.py rollback .
```

I get a terminal error that

> appcfg.py: error: Directory does not contain an app.yaml configuration
>   file

Thanks for any direction.

**Update**

I think I finally found out where it is but now I am getting permission denied when I do

```
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.3/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.3/bin/appcfg.sh rollback war
```

Comment: read the error message, you need to run it from the directory where you put the app.yaml file

Comment: @marcadian when I am developing python I have a `app.yaml`. But I never see one in my java project directory. That's what I need help with. I look all over in the java project and there is no such thing. Again, this is an endpoint project: App-engine connected android project. And eclipse is giving me the error. Is there an eclipse solution perhaps?

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11675706/5463601) answer.
This will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11675706/5463601) answer.
This will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Mac, try

```
appcfg.sh rollback
```

Comment: App Engine documentation for Java suggests appcfg.sh, so I would try that first. I am using this command for a few years now with no problems.

Comment: oh got it, I thought the update command is the same for any language :P

Comment: @AndreiVolgin i am getting message: `bash: appcfg.sh command not found`, i am doing this in the Termial of Android Studio.

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal - You have to be in the right directory or provide the full path.

Answer (score 1):

You can also avoid having to specify your app directory (as it doesn't seen to work for you), by specifying your app id and version in the command itself:

```
appcfg.py rollback -A your_app_id -V your_app_version
```

If you have multiple modules then you will need to specify that too with the -M switch.

Comment: This is the only one that gives me a print out that's not `command not found`. But it's the one that complains about `app.yaml` not being found. But then it also shows `Usage: appcfg.py [options] rollback <directory> | <file>`. What are the options for rollback? I don't see them at address https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find you [don't have execute permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099674/google-app-engine-make-a-rollback-with-appcfg-sh) on `appcfg`

So, if you change to your SDK directory and run

`chmod 755 appcfg.sh`

Then

`appcfg.sh rollback <path_to_app>/war`

should work.  If not, you may have a `WebContent` directory, in which case use the path to that. Essentially, `appcfg` wants to see the `WEB-INF` directory which contains your `appengine-web.xml` for the module you're rolling back.

Answer (score 0):

On MAC -
in terminal, goto where  your sdk directory  - /Users/*user*/Desktop/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.20/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.20/bin

do

> chmod 777 *

run

> bash appcfg.sh rollback /Users/*user*/Desktop/builder/war

The last parameter is the location of the war inside your project

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it using this command on mac:
python /usr/local/bin/appcfg.py -verbose --no_cookies --email=account@gmail.com --passin rollback directoryname

where directoryname was the folder where the app.yaml is located. For my case, it was on dropbox folder. so firstly I went to that directory using terminal then I pasted: python /usr/local/bin/appcfg.py -verbose --no_cookies --email=account@gmail.com --passin app

where app defines file name app.yaml

Answer (score 0):

**This is for java project using app engine**
*This happens your previous deployment not successfully deployed*

---

go to app engine sdk

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.49\bin
```

then add

> syntax: appcfg.sh rollback your project war folder

Example:  `appcfg.sh rollback E:myproject\war`

Enough!!!

Comment: Please don't post text as images. Instead copy-paste and format it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows user,

```
Syntax: "<appengine sdk bin folder path>\appcfg" rollback "<war path of your project"

Example: "C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-java-
sdk\1.9.44\appengine-java-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.44\bin\appcfg" rollback "D:\helloworld\war"
```

Output of the above will be something like this,

```
********************************************************
There is a new version of the SDK available.
-----------
Latest SDK:
Release: 1.9.49
Timestamp: Wed Jan 18 23:03:47 IST 2017
API versions: [1.0]

-----------
Your SDK:
Release: 1.9.44
Timestamp: Sat Aug 20 03:11:38 IST 2016
API versions: [1.0]

-----------
Please visit https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads for the latest SD
K.
********************************************************
Reading application configuration data...


Beginning interaction for module default...
0% Rolling back the update.
Success.
Cleaning up temporary files for module default...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI on this: I was using the Eclipse java plugin on Mac (so otherwise didn't have the SDK anywhere), found the command file by digging into the Eclipse package there etc, but predictably enough it didn't run. So I just downloaded the appengine Java SDK, unzipped it, went into bin, ran ./appcfg rollback my/proj command as you see here.

Leave that terminal window open, do not close it, read on...

It opens a web browser and tells you in a very bare bones way to "copy a code and return to the application". I haven't had to roll back a deploy in quite some time, but I don't remember this step. Anyway, I had no idea what that meant until I happened to look at the terminal where I ran the appcfg command, which was now waiting for me to paste in that code. Then all was well.